# Missing information when deploying Connected App

Tags: metadata-api, connected-apps

I want to deploy a connected app in an other orgs but there is some parameters I can't find in the  [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_connectedapp.htm) (Can't find parameters in the screen shot)

[image: value I can't migrate]
For exemple, I can't find a way to set the Timeout Value for session policy

When I retrive the metadata of the CA, i got this :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ConnectedApp xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <contactEmail>myemailadresse@test.com</contactEmail>
    <contactPhone>009</contactPhone>
    <label>MyconnectedApp</label>
    <oauthConfig>
        <callbackUrl>mycallbackurl</callbackUrl>
        <consumerKey>JKTzFSqY.2NyPRwSwMCcuD5VEWKC87QSVld6ceWChIujMERvNts...</consumerKey>
        <scopes>Full</scopes>
    </oauthConfig>
</ConnectedApp>
```

Did I miss out on something?

Edit : The context is that, when we refresh our sandbox from prod, Client ID and Client Secret of connected app change. It take a lot of time to reconfigure everything, so, we want to find a way to keep the same Client ID and Client Secret after refreshing SB. I was thinking that i can make a package with every connected app for each SB and deploy it after refresh to keep all parameters of CA unchanged

Comment: You only need the connected app in a single org. Why are you trying to deploy it to other orgs?

Comment: A connected app can't be deployed as per my experience. It has a unique Consumer Key across all Salesforce Organizations. What are trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: The context is that, when we refresh our sandbox from prod, Client ID and Client Secret of connected app change. It take a lot of time to reconfigure everything, so, we want to find a way to keep the same Client ID and Client Secret after refreshing SB. I was thinking that i can make a package with every connected app for each SB and deploy it after refresh to keep all parameters of CA unchanged

Comment: You need to copy the metadata from the source org and create a local project and then paste the metadata in local and do a save to server. If you are using a certificate make sure you change it to use default certificate before you do save to server in target. it should work if not let me know.

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty I retrieve the same .connectedApp file from the source org